# Spring boot auto config of datasource - Driver must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I switched my Spring boot config for my datasource to use the type SimpleDriverDataSource, but once I did that I get an error about "Driver must not be null"

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(SimpleDriverDataSource.class).build();
}
```

If I remove the call to .type(SimpleDriverDataSource.class) then it works fine again.

Do I need to change my property names somehow?

```
datasource.url=jdbc:blah blah blah
datasource.driverClassName=blah blah
```

I did attempt datasource.driver instead, but that didnt change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the SimpleDriverDataSource class, you'll see that you have setDriverClass() method. So, you need to change your configuration to `datasource.driverClass` to use be able to create the driver property.

Or you can create your bean like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    Driver driver = new org.postgresql.Driver();
    return new SimpleDriverDataSource(driver, 
            "url",
            "user",
            "pass");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had some trouble with unpopulated `DataSource` values when using `DataSourceBuilder`. For me the soultion below worked:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public DataSourceProperties developerPortalDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
public DataSource developerPortalDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}
```

Just replace the `HikariDataSource.class` with the DataSource implementation you're using. Hope it helps.